# Android, Fit an Image Inside an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

i try to fit any image inside a diamond shape. My image is dynamic, how can i handle this ?

This is what I do:

[image]

and this is what I'm trying for:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean that your image is dynamic? dynamic in size? where the face is?

Comment: this concept is called masking

Comment: I mean my image is changeable upon my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like [this](https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView) this creates a custom shape `ImageView` and then you can use it as you see fit.. then you can add some edge color to have the effect you want